# How to access a cell ignoring the Title?

Tags: python, prettytable

I;m trying to access an element of a cell from pretty table. When I tried that the title of the pretty table also comes as part of the output. is there a way to ignore it?

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

table = PrettyTable(["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"])
table.title = 'TESTING'
table.add_row(["A", "B", "C"])
table.add_row(["F", "O", "O"])
table.add_row(["B", "A", "R"])


for row in table:
    row.border = False
    row.header = False
    print(row.get_string(fields = ['Column 1']).strip())
```

output is as follows:

```
| TESTING |
  A
| TESTING |
  F
| TESTING |
  B
```

But i want only the fields particularly the cell values and i dont want the title.
can someone kindly help.

i tried searching throught the documentation of prettytable but could not find it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like `get_string` provides a straight forward API to achieve that, but we can cheat by using `\r` as the temporary title and use `NONE` for `vrules`:

```py
from prettytable import PrettyTable, NONE
...
for row in table:
    print(row.get_string(fields=['Column 1'],
                         border=False,
                         header=False,
                         title='\r',
                         vrules=NONE).strip())
```

Or we can use a lower-level API:

```py
for row in table.rows:
    print(row[0])
```

Both will output

```
A
F
B
```

To get a specific cell's value you can use `start` and `stop` arguments which are zero-based and are inclusive-exclusive (like Python's `range`):

```py
print(table.get_string(fields=['Column 1'],
                       border=False,
                       header=False,
                       title='\r',
                       vrules=NONE,
                       start=1,
                       end=2).strip())
```

will output

```
F
```

Comment: Thanks.. thats exactly what i wanted. Also is there a way to get a particular cell value.??

Comment: @SVIJAY See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Documentation at PyPI shows the following Style options

**border** - A boolean option (must be True or False). Controls whether a border is drawn around the table.

**header** - A boolean option (must be True or False). Controls whether the first row of the table is a header showing the names of all the fields.

**hrules** - Controls printing of horizontal rules after rows. Allowed values: FRAME, HEADER, ALL, NONE - note that these are variables defined inside the prettytable module so make sure you import them or use prettytable.FRAME etc.

**vrules** - Controls printing of vertical rules between columns. Allowed values: FRAME, ALL, NONE.

So try the following -

```
table.border = False
table.header = False
table.vrules = 2
table.title = ''
```

followed by

```
print(table[:])
```

or

```
for row in table:
    print(row)
```